# oracle database 19c installation occurs error

Tags: database, oracle

I'm trying to install oracle database, but the installation doesn't work like below.
[image]

I tried to install this as admin install, but doesn't work too.

What I can try? please give me some help

Comment: What to do? Reading & following the **Installation Guide** usually helps.

Comment: There really isn't enough information for us to give you any advice. For instance, you haven't even told us what operating system you're using. Oracle 19c is professional grade software, which means installing and administering it requires a base level of pre-existing knowledge. If you just want to practice Oracle SQL I suggest you consider installing [Oracle on Docker](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images) or signing up for [a **free** Oracle cloud instance](https://www.oracle.com/uk/cloud/free/)

Comment: I solved it. It was a problem of firewall and developer mode.